# How to assign Function from a module to a variable in Erlang?

Tags: module, erlang

I am new to Erlang. If I do this

```
H = fun(X) -> X*X.
```

Then it is fine. But if I move that function to a module, it says "Illegal Expression". For example this

```
H = misc_functions:square.
```

Please help.

Comment: There is no fundamental difference in using `fun misc_function:square/1` or `fun (X) -> misc_function:square(X) end`. The first is syntactic sugar for the second and is converted to it very early in the compiler.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Erlang function references require the keyword `fun` and the arity.  Suppose that `square` takes a single parameter, the correct assignment is:

```
H = fun misc_function:square/1
```

Comment: is the usage then `H(Param)`? E.g., is this a shorthand form of @Alin's answer?

Comment: this answer does not seem to work when parse_transforms are used but the more verbose version in Alin's does

Answer (score 2):

You can also do something like that:

```
1> F = fun(X) -> misc_function:square(X) end.
#Fun<erl_eval.6.13229925>
2> F(4).
16
3>
```

Defining a function that calls inside your desired function.

Comment: This answer, although more verbose, works even when `parse_transforms` are used: I don't think Little Bobby's answer does (I tried it)